# How do I pass a form into an object's body attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have an array of objects:

```
const items = [
    {
        head: 'Contributions',
        subhead: 'Search by person.',
        body: 'Empty'
    },
    ...
];
```

going into this accordion:

```
const SearchMenu = (props) => {
    const [selectedCard, setSelectedCard] = useState(null);
    return (
        <Accordion>

            {items.map((item, index) => (
                <div className="searchOption" key={index.toString()}>
                    <Card className="card">
                        {renderHeader(index, selectedCard, setSelectedCard, item)}

                        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={index.toString()}>
                            <div className="body">
                                <Card.Body className="card card-body">{item.body}</Card.Body>
                            </div>
                        </Accordion.Collapse>
                    </Card>
                    <hr className="divider"></hr>
                </div>
            ))}
        </Accordion>
    );
};
```

and the body of each object will be a functional component. How can I pass this component into the body of the objects? I have not made the components yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this :

```
const items = [
    {
        head: 'Contributions',
        subhead: 'Search by person.',
        body: <Test />
    }
];
```

```js
const Test = () => <h1>test</h1>

const items = [
    {
        head: 'Contributions',
        subhead: 'Search by person.',
        body: <Test />
    }
];

const SearchMenu = (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
          {items.map((item, index) => (
              <div>
                {item.body}
              </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<SearchMenu />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```